# What film do I buy for a Kodak Star 500 AF point and shoot?

Tags: film, kodak

What film do I buy for my Kodak Star 500 AF film camera?

Answer (score 3):

The Kodak Star 500 camera uses 35mm film, technically known as [135 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/135_film).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the size, it's 35mm.
If you're looking for specific brands, it depends on your skill level. If you're just starting out, or don't want to spend a lot of money on the film I suggest you go with Fujicolor, as they are relatively cheap and are good quality.